# how to remove class while mouseleave in the scrollbar side?

Tags: javascript, jquery, qtip2

I used the qtip2 jquery plugin.I fix some menu in the right side of the browser when the mouse enter the menu that will diplay a qtip and add a class like shadow.when the mouse is unfocus the qtip that qtip is disappear automatically and that shadow class will be remove automatically.

there is scroll bar in the right side of the browser.when thee qtip is unfocus the qtip inside the browser side means the qtip is disappear and shadow class is remove.but if mouse move the scroll bar side that qtip is disappear automaticlly but that shadow class is not remove.

my code is:

```
hide: function(event, api) {
    $(this, api.elements.content).on('mouseout', function(){
       $(api.target).removeClass("hover");
    });
}
```